# Excel: Formatting text into a recognisable date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-dates

I have a .csv file with many rows where the date is formatted as you see in column A. I manually copied and then changed the date to how I want it to be in column B where it's also recognised by Excel as a date (and not text).

My question is does anyone know how I can get Excel to format the date like this automatically via some forumula magic or some other method?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another formula that should return the correct date.  This does require Office 365:

```
=--TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),",","")," "),,{2,1,3,5}))
```

This removes the `,` and then rearranges the order.  The `--` turns it into a number.

If the month abbreviations do not match the local settings it will not work

[image]

---

For older versions:

```
=--(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ",REPT(" ",999)),999,999)) & " " &
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ",REPT(" ",999)),1,999)) & " " &
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ",REPT(" ",999)),1998,999)) & " " &
TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," ",REPT(" ",999)),3996,999)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shorter formula for older versions:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A2,1,8,MID(A2,5,2)&"/"&LEFT(A2,3)&"/")," @ "," ")
```

(English-locale)

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A2,1,8,MID(A2,5,2)&"/"&FIND(LEFT(A2,3),"  JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec")/3&"/")," @ "," ")
```

(non-English locale)